# Customer login / register pop up modal

Tags: magento-2.1, customer, login, register

I need to remove a "OK" button from customer register/login modal pop up and can't find the template anywhere. I can find the `login.phtml` file, however, the footer modal is not there.

Working on **Magento ver. 2.1.8** and a custom theme.

Can anyone direct me?

[image]
[image]

**UPDATE:**

Grep result:

```
[frontend]$ grep -rni "Magento_Ui/js/modal/alert" /microcloud/domains/operm2/domains/domain.co.uk/http/app/design/frontend
/microcloud/domains/operm2/domains/domain.co.uk/http/app/design/frontend/Venustheme/cricket_child/Magento_Checkout/web/js/sidebar.js:11:    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/alert',
grep: /microcloud/domains/operm2/domains/domain.co.uk/http/app/design/frontend/Venustheme/cricket_child/Ves_Themesettings/web/css/fancybox_loading@2x.gif: No such file or directory
grep: /microcloud/domains/operm2/domains/domain.co.uk/http/app/design/frontend/Venustheme/cricket_child/Ves_Themesettings/web/css/paneltool.css: No such file or directory
grep: /microcloud/domains/operm2/domains/domain.co.uk/http/app/design/frontend/Venustheme/cricket_child/Ves_Themesettings/web/css/fancybox_overlay.png: No such file or directory
grep: /microcloud/domains/operm2/domains/domain.co.uk/http/app/design/frontend/Venustheme/cricket_child/Ves_Themesettings/web/css/fancybox_sprite.png: No such file or directory
grep: /microcloud/domains/operm2/domains/domain.co.uk/http/app/design/frontend/Venustheme/cricket_child/Ves_Themesettings/web/css/fancybox_loading.gif: No such file or directory
grep: /microcloud/domains/operm2/domains/domain.co.uk/http/app/design/frontend/Venustheme/cricket_child/Ves_Themesettings/web/css/styles.css: No such file or directory
grep: /microcloud/domains/operm2/domains/domain.co.uk/http/app/design/frontend/Venustheme/cricket_child/Ves_Themesettings/web/css/jquery.fancybox.css: No such file or directory
grep: /microcloud/domains/operm2/domains/domain.co.uk/http/app/design/frontend/Venustheme/cricket_child/Ves_Themesettings/web/css/fancybox_sprite@2x.png: No such file or directory
grep: /microcloud/domains/operm2/domains/domain.co.uk/http/app/design/frontend/Venustheme/cricket/Ves_Megamenu/web/css/styles.css: No such file or directory
```

Comment: can you add your login popup js code ?

Comment: Can you tell me how to find the JS for this pop-up or a way to track it down?

Comment: Give me the website link.

Comment: Did you manage to find anything?

Comment: More information required to solve this issue.

Comment: What information do you need and I do my best to find it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this is a custom theme I'm not sure the exact location of files needed to modify. Search your custom theme for `Magento_Ui/js/modal/alert`. Something like `grep -ir "Magento_Ui/js/modal/alert"` via **ssh** from the themes directory will show all files within the theme that have the **modal widget**. One of these will be your login modal which we can modify.

The modals look like below however am not sure there is an option to hide the footer. This could be achieved by doing similar to the below:

```
require([
                'jquery',
                'Magento_Ui/js/modal/alert'
            ],
            function($, alert) {
               alert({
                    title: "Hello",
                    content: "World",
                    autoOpen: true,
                    clickableOverlay: false,
                    focus: "",
                    actions: {
                        always: function(){
                            console.log("modal closed");
                        }
                    }
                });
                $(".modal-footer").hide();
            }
        );
```

Adding the `$(".modal-footer").hide();` like above will hide the footer.

Comment: Have a look at the result from grep in my updated question

Comment: I cant see what the file would be from there unless its the first sidebar one check that out see if that is the modal in question. Are there any modules with this theme?

Comment: There is nothing regarding `modal-footer`. Not even one mention :/

Comment: Nah there wont be. I added that in.

Comment: I would check the code folder with the same grep command

Comment: Have you got a url i could look at quickly?

Comment: Yes, go to www.operationvape.co.uk and if you click on login it will bring this pop-up

Comment: oh i like a nice vape

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72209/discussion-between-harri-and-bare-feet).